# Can I CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE in SQLAlchemy without appending to Table._prefixes?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, temp-tables

I'd like to create a temporary table in SQLAlchemy. I can build a `CREATE TABLE` statement with a `TEMPORARY` clause by calling `table._prefixes.append('TEMPORARY')` against a `Table` object, but that's less elegant than `table.select().prefix_with()` used to add a prefix to data manipulation language expressions.

Is there an equivalent to `.prefix_with()` for DDL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, `prefix_with()` is defined for SELECT and INSERT only. But convenient way to add prefix to CREATE TABLE statement is passing it into table definition:

```
t = Table(
    't', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    # ...
    prefixes=['TEMPORARY'],
)
```

Comment: I was trying to make a temporary table that looked like a reflected table. It wound up being more trouble than it was worth, trying to derive new Table objects from existing ones instead of making a function that returns several similar Table objects.

Comment: What Engine does this work with? I cannot get "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE" to work with MSSQL