# SQLAlchemy temporary table with Declarative Base

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, temporary

I need a temporary table in my programme. I have seen that this can be achieved with the "mapper" syntax in this way:

```
t = Table(
    't', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    # ...
    prefixes=['TEMPORARY'],
)
```

Seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842902/can-i-create-temporary-table-in-sqlalchemy-without-appending-to-table-prefixes)

But, my whole code is using the declarative base, it is what I understand, and I would like to stick to it. There is the possibility of using a [hybrid approach](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/declarative.html#using-a-hybrid-approach-with-table)  but if possible I'd avoid it.

This is a simplified version of how my declarative class looks like:

```
import SQLAlchemy as alc
class Tempo(Base):
    """
    Class for temporary table used to process data coming from xlsx
    @param Base Declarative Base
    """

    # TODO: make it completely temporary

    __tablename__ = 'tempo'

    drw = alc.Column(alc.String)
    date = alc.Column(alc.Date)
    check_number = alc.Column(alc.Integer)
```

Thanks in advance!

EDITED WITH THE NEW PROBLEMS:

Now the class looks like this:

```
import SQLAlchemy as alc

class Tempo(Base):
        """
        Class for temporary table used to process data coming from xlsx
        @param Base Declarative Base
        """

        # TODO: make it completely temporary

        __tablename__ = 'tempo'
        __table_args__ = {'prefixes': ['TEMPORARY']}

        drw = alc.Column(alc.String)
        date = alc.Column(alc.Date)
        check_number = alc.Column(alc.Integer)
```

And when I try to insert data in this table, I get the following error message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such table:
tempo u'INSERT INTO tempo (...) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' (....)
```

It seems the table doesn't exist just by declaring it. I have seen something like create_all() that might be the solution for this (it's funny to see how new ideas come while explaining thoroughly)

Then again, thank you very much!

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it possible to use `__table_args__`? See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_tables.html#orm-declarative-table-configuration

```
class Tempo(Base):
    """
    Class for temporary table used to process data coming from xlsx
    @param Base Declarative Base
    """

    # TODO: make it completely temporary

    __tablename__ = 'tempo'
    __table_args__ = {'prefixes': ['TEMPORARY']}

    drw = alc.Column(alc.String)
    date = alc.Column(alc.Date)
    check_number = alc.Column(alc.Integer)
```

Comment: Uhm, I shouldnt have gone that fast. 

Insertion seems to be ok, but when I try to commit, it crashes. I thought this makes sense for temporary tables, but when I try to query without commiting, it also crashes.

How do I query the data inside of the tempo table?

I'm not very experienced with SQLite...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's weird! I haven't tested this myself, but I thought `__table_args__` were simply passed to the table constructor. I don't know enough about SQLite to give you a definite answer. Could you update your question with the error message you get when it crashes?

Comment: Hi again, I just edited the original message with the extra explanation. Thanks again!

Comment: Simply declaring the table is not enough for any table (temporary or not). You have to call `create_all` to actually create the tables. See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/declarative.html#accessing-the-metadata

Comment: Thanks, works for me. You have to have `alembic>=1.5.0` since prior to that `prefixes` wasn't picked up by autogenerate.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but if anyone out there wants to create a temp table from an existing declarative table model on the fly rather than having it always be a part of your model/code, you can try the following approach. Copying `__table_args__` is a little tricky since it can have multiple formats and any `Index` objects need to be recreated so they aren't associated with the old table.

```py
import time

from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable


def copy_table_args(model, **kwargs):
    """Try to copy existing __table_args__, override params with kwargs"""
    table_args = model.__table_args__

    if isinstance(table_args, tuple):
        new_args = []
        for arg in table_args:
            if isinstance(arg, dict):
                table_args_dict = arg.copy()
                table_args_dict.update(**kwargs)
                new_args.append(arg)
            elif isinstance(arg, sa.Index):
                index = sa.Index(
                    arg.name,
                    *[col for col in arg.columns.keys()],
                    unique=arg.unique,
                    **arg.kwargs,
                )
                new_args.append(index)
            else:
                # TODO: need to handle Constraints
                raise Exception(f"Unhandled table arg: {arg}")
        table_args = tuple(new_args)
    elif isinstance(table_args, dict):
        table_args = {
            k: (v.copy() if hasattr(v, "copy") else v) for k, v in table_args.items()
        }
        table_args.update(**kwargs)
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Unexpected __table_args__ type: {table_args}")

    return table_args


def copy_table_from_model(conn, model, **kwargs):
    model_name = model.__name__ + "Tmp"
    table_name = model.__table__.name + "_" + str(time.time()).replace(".", "_")
    table_args = copy_table_args(model, extend_existing=True)

    args = {c.name: c.copy() for c in model.__table__.c}
    args["__tablename__"] = table_name
    args["__table_args__"] = table_args

    copy_model = type(model_name, model.__bases__, args)
    print(str(CreateTable(copy_model.__table__)))
    copy_model.__table__.create(conn)
    return copy_model


def temp_table_from_model(conn, model, **kwargs):
    return copy_table_from_model(conn, model, prefixes=["TEMPORARY"])
```

Note: I haven't added logic to handle copying Constraints, and this is lightly tested against MySQL. Also note that if you do this with non-temporary tables and auto-named indexes (i.e. `Column(..., index=True)`) then this may not play nice with `alembic`.