# Create a temporary table in MySQL using Pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, temp-tables

Pandas has a great feature, where you can write your dataframe to a table in SQL.

`df.to_sql(con=cnx, name='some_table_name', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql', index=False)`

Is there a way to make a temporary table this way?

There is nothing in the documentation as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 20):

The `DataFrame.to_sql()` uses the built into pandas [`pandas.io.sql` package](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries), which itself relies on the SQLAlchemy as a database abstraction layer. In order to create a "temporary" table in SQLAlchemy ORM, [you need to supply a prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842902/can-i-create-temporary-table-in-sqlalchemy-without-appending-to-table-prefixes):

```
t = Table(
    't', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    # ...
    prefixes=['TEMPORARY'],
)
```

From what I see, `pandas.io.sql` [does not allow you to specify the `prefixes`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/sql.py#L685) or easily change the way tables are created.

One way to approach this problem would be to *create the temporary table beforehand* and use `to_sql()` with `if_exists="append"` (all using the same database connection).

---

Here is also what I've tried to do: override the `pandas.io.sql.SQLTable`'s `_create_table_setup()` method and pass the `prefixes` to the `Table` constructor. For some reason, the table was still created non-temporary. Not sure if it would help, but here is the code I was using: [gist](https://gist.github.com/alecxe/44682f79b18f0c82a99c). This is kind of hacky, but I hope it would at least serve as an example code to get you started on this approach.

Comment: The function `_create_table_setup` is called only in `__init__` to set the `table` property. To create a table with `pandas.io.sql.SQLTable`, you call `create`, which calls `_execute_create`, which overwrites the `table` property. That's why your attempt didn't work. Instead, you need to edit `_execute_create`: https://gist.github.com/alecxe/44682f79b18f0c82a99c#gistcomment-2359365

Answer (score 7):

## Easy workaround without fancy magic

This was a quick and easy workaround for me.

Simply apply a RegEx to the generated SQL to add in whatever statements you want.

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

# Get the SQL that would be generated by the create table statement
create_table_sql = pd.io.sql.get_schema(df, tmp_table_name)

# Replace the `CREATE TABLE` part of the generated statement with 
# whatever you need.
create_tmp_table_sql = re.sub(
    "^(CREATE TABLE)?",
    "CREATE TEMP TABLE",
    create_table_sql
)
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```py
# Write to the database in a transaction (psycopg2)
with conn.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute(create_tmp_table_sql)
    output = io.StringIO()
    df.to_csv(output, sep="\t", header=False, index=False, na_rep="NULL")
    output.seek(0)
    cur.copy_from(output, tmp_table_name, null="NULL")
```

Credit to [Aseem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47984180/1772238) for a fast
way to write to Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit hacky and it doesn't technically create a temporary table, it just acts like one, but you could create use the [`@contextmanager` decorator from `contextlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) to create the table upon opening the context and drop it upon close. Could look something like:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

import numpy as np
import sqlalchemy as sqla
import pandas as pd


@contextmanager
def temp_table(frame, tbl, eng, *args, **kwargs):
    frame.to_sql(tbl, eng, *args, **kwargs)
    yield
    eng.execute('DROP TABLE {}'.format(tbl))

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(21, size=(10, 10)))
cnx = sqla.create_engine(conn_string)

with temp_table(df, 'some_table_name', cnx, if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql', index=False):
    # do stuff with "some_table_name"
```

I tested it using Teradata and it works fine. I don't have a MySQL laying around that I can test it out on, but as long as `DROP` statements work in MySQL, it should work as intended.